# Suppress powershell output messages

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-power-tools

I have a TFS 2013 Update 2 buildserver. When I build a project, I checkout some files, alter some things and check it in again. This works great.
The only problem is when someone has checkout one of those files, the buildserver will see that as an error and the build will be partially succeeded. Actually it is just an information message but the build sees it as an error. How can I suppress those messages?

I have the following Powershell command:

```
Add-TfsPendingChange -Edit -Item $PathToFolderToCheckout -Recurse
```

The command is from the TFS 2013 Power Tools.

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

- Add `-ErrorAction` with `Igonore` and `SilentlyContinue`
- Add `-Out-Null`
- Try and empty Catch

The message that is thrown for each file is:
*Path to file*: opened for edit in *Workspace*;Ralph Jansen

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe it needs to be in the standard output stream to be sent to null. Try this:

```
$Null = Add-TfsPendingChange -Edit -Item $PathToFolderToCheckout -Recurse *>&1
```

*>&1 redirects all output to standard output and $null is a reserved variable for this purpose. It is more efficient than piping to out-null.

Another alternative could be to set the action preference for errors. I've seen before where cmdlets don't seem to acknowledge the -ErrorAction common parameter.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
Add-TfsPendingChange -Edit -Item $PathToFolderToCheckout -Recurse
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're talking about? It would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

After some efforts, I successfully get it for our Tfs builds! \o/

You have to end the command line with  `*>&1 | out-null`

For exemple:

```
Add-TfsPendingChange -Edit -Item $PathToFolderToCheckout -Recurse *>&1 | out-null
```

The side effect is that all the messages that cause the errors are lost.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

```powershell
Add-TfsPendingChange -Edit -Item $PathToFolderToCheckout -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -wa 0 | Out-null
```

or

```powershell
[void](Add-TfsPendingChange -Edit -Item $PathToFolderToCheckout -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -wa 0)
```

You can also assign result of your cmdlet to a variable(and do nothing with it):

```powershell
$throwaway = Add-TfsPendingChange -Edit -Item $PathToFolderToCheckout -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -wa 0
```

Comment: What does the spurious output look like? If it is a warning you can add `-wa 0` switch to one of the above commands and try again

Comment: The output is only the message that I sayed in the question above... I guess it's the same message that appears in the output window of Visual Studio if you checkout a file that is already checked out by someone else... Just information/warning message...

Comment: Try the amended answer with `-wa` switch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Add-TfsPendingChange -Edit -Item $PathToFolderToCheckout -Recurse 2>&1 >$null
```

The `2>&1` argument redirects `stderr` to `stdout` and the `>$null` argument redirects `stdout` to null so nothing will be displayed.

Or, if you only want to hide the data being sent to `stderr`, just redirect that:

```
Add-TfsPendingChange -Edit -Item $PathToFolderToCheckout -Recurse 2>$null
```

Comment: I don't use TFS, so I can't test your command directly. Can you show us a screenshot of what's happening?